# Can you temporary grant a user permission to avoid captchas in drupal 7?

Tags: forms, captcha, users

I have a module which alters a webform's form. Depending on the user agent, I want to grant the ***current*** user the permission to skip captchas, so that the captcha block wont appear at the end of my webform. The problem is, within the init function of my module, if I enable the following line:

```
if (functionWhichChecksStuff()) {
        user_role_grant_permissions(DRUPAL_ANONYMOUS_RID, array('skip CAPTCHA'));
    }
```

the permission is being granted for ALL anons, every time since it actually grants the permission to that user role *permanently*.

Is there a way or function which does that *dynamically and temporary*?

Comment: So by "user" you mean always the anonymous user, not a logged in user?

Comment: correct, the sessioned user if you will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are basic problems with your approach:

- All anon users are one user for Drupal. They share common UID 0, so they are one user. And HTTP is a stateless protocol, so you can't decide "it's the same user" basing on connection. In Drupal 7 sessions are not guaranteed for anonymous users, so you can't use them reliably for that purpose either.
- If you will try to modify $user->roles, it will add a role for current http **call** all right, but it will not regenerate caches, like admin/reports/status/rebuild or views caches based on roles.
- hook_init docs says: This hook is not run on cached pages.

So, this is no-go by design, and if you need to give some privileges or options by browser session, you need to implement your own solutions, like cookies. There is a list of [modules that works that way](http://drupal.org/node/1647824), you can use their code for reference.

Comment: "In Drupal 7 sessions are not guaranteed for anonymous users, so you can't use them reliably for that purpose either." - even if this was the case, webform does provide useful and reliable information reguarding that point.
i accomplished to simply unset the captcha block and disable caching for the whole node

Comment: Should work, as long as all you want is to grant that "permission" just during one form lifetime. I assumed your question to be a tad more general - like that solution should work even when form does not exist yet, work for all/choosen forms, work even if exact requirement is other than $_SERVER value...

Comment: well in this case i have a specific nid so its always that form. thanks anyway :)